# Loop over arrayfun with MATLAB

Tags: matlab

In MATLAB, I'd like to use `arrayfun` in a loop without using the function `for`.

The general syntax is the following:

```
arrayfun(@(x,i,j) func(x), M{i,j})
```

where `(i,j)` is the index of a matrix `M` applied in the function `func(x)` where `x = M`.

The purpose is to apply `arrayfun(@(x,i,j) func(x), M{i,j})` for all `i=1,..,n`
and `j=1,...,n` whithout a loop.

Thank you

Comment: Can you shows us a [mcve]

Comment: Often, your function `func` is very important to this - can you show us either the function itself, or a minimal example (see comment by Ander Biguri) of that function?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `for`?

Comment: `arrayfun` **is** a loop, and it's slower than `for`. You better take @excaza advice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Xzibit would say *"Yo dawg, I heard you like everything but `for`, so we put an `arrayfun` in your `arrayfun` so you can loop while you're looping"*

```
result = reshape(arrayfun(             ...
    @(k) arrayfun(@(x) func(x), M{k}), ...
    1:numel(M),                        ...
    'UniformOutput', false ...
), size(M));
```

or even better:

```
result = arrayfun( ...
    @(k) arrayfun(@func,  M{k}), ...
    reshape(1:numel(M),size(M)), ...
    'UniformOutput', false       ...
);
```

But—come on!—one can do better MATLAB than Xzibit! :-)